# Kubernetes deployment high memory usage

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

[image]

[image]

I am using python flask in GKE contianer and moemory is increasing inside pod. I have set limit to pod but it's getting killed.

I am thinking it's memory leak can anybody suggest something after watching this. As disk increase memory also increase and there are some page faults also.

Is there anything container side linux os (using python-slim base). Memory is not coming back to  os or python flask memory management issue ?

To check memory leak i have added stackimpact to application.

[image]

Please help...!
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's definitely leaking disk space (a log file?).  Without any application source code it's basically impossible to give any hints as to what might be going wrong, though.  This isn't something that can be usefully diagnosed from the Kubernetes level.

Comment: @DavidMaze thankyou for writing answer i am trying to run profiler inside pod. found out this so working on this  now :https://stackimpact.com/

Comment: @DavidMaze is there anything like disk leak ? i have idea of memory leak so working on it. We are generating xls file inside pods and upload it to bucket later. so is there anything generating files can cause issue ?

Comment: we actually need some logs/YAML to understand the issue with just a few graphs we may only provide an educated guess

Comment: @ErnestoU can you please specify which logs i will update it with it. also updated question with profiler graph for memory leak.

Comment: @ErnestoU you please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114700/kubernetes-pod-auto-restart-with-exit-137-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you added a resource memory limit to each GKE Deployment when the [memory limit](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits) was hit, the pod was killed, rescheduled, and should restarted and the other pods on the node should be fine.

You can find more information by running this command:

```
kubectl describe pod <YOUR_POD_NAME>

kubectl top pods
```

Please note if you put in a memory request that is larger than the amount of memory on your nodes, the pod will never be scheduled.

And if the Pod cannot be [scheduled](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#PodUnschedulable) because of insufficient resources or some configuration error You might encounter an error indicating a lack memory or another resource. If a Pod is stuck in Pending it means that it can not be scheduled onto a node.  In this case you need to delete Pods, adjust resource requests, or add new nodes to your cluster. You can find more information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/#my-pods-are-pending-with-event-message-failedscheduling).

Additionally, as per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/small-cluster-tuning#horizontal_pod_autoscaling), [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) (HPA) scales the replicas of your deployments based on metrics like memory or CPU usage.

Comment: thankyou for writing answer but i got your points here issue is not node memory or insufficient memory. All pod and replicas works properly but for one microservice disk & memory increase automatically.