# Rediness & Livenesss failing at random interval

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine

We are running flask microservices on GKE. The main application that accepts all traffic and divides it in other services is restarting.

POD's readiness & liveness start going timeout at random intervals. however, we are running 5 pods of particular service and it's stateless application. One thing I have noticed memory also keeps increasing with time.

is it due to the docker `python-slim` image at a certain level no able to handle the application and for continuous memory increasing in pod is it like OS `python-slim` not releasing memory?

**Note** : This behavior only on production not on staging(running single application pod).

what cloud be the reason behind this, please help. Thanks

**Update** 
liveness & readiness probe config

```
readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /k8/readiness
              port: 9595
            initialDelaySeconds: 25
            periodSeconds: 8
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 30
        livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /k8/liveness
              port: 9595
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 8
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 30
```

Comment: It looks like connected to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134207/kubernetes-deployment-high-memory-usage. In my opinion, you should try to increase limits, monitor memory usage and follow https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits. BTW, as you can see at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/ "While lightweight and easy to use, Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well."

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza thanks for writing answers & suggestion i have tried everything but no help so far. the resource limit set is more than enough.

Comment: Do you have any request handlers that can block and lock up the thread? If you have too many of those and they al happen at once you can run out of worker threads and be unable to process new requests.

Answer (score 1):

While it's a bit difficult to provide an answer without looking at the manifests, events, or other traces from your cluster, I've often seen this case happens when people misunderstand/misconfigure readiness and liveness probes and/or not scaling correctly.

For example, it is possible that you have a probe:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 443
  failureThreshold: 1
  periodSeconds: 10
```

This means, check every 10 seconds, if http `GET` to `/healthz:443` is OK, if it fails once, stop sending traffic (since it's a readiness probe only).

If you don't set `timeoutSeconds`, by default the value is 1 second.

What can often happen under load, is that the `/healthz:443` endpoint takes longer and longer to respond if additional pods are not added and the latency keeps increasing.

Eventually, once it hovers around the 1 second, a single timeout would cause readiness to fail - this is a best case scenario.

If your liveness probe is configured this way, you would have pod restarts which is way worse.

This [article](https://srcco.de/posts/kubernetes-liveness-probes-are-dangerous.html) does a great job of explaining why it's not always wise to use liveness probes (unless you have a very specific check for it).

In the case of load causing this, you might actually be OK with a 1 second timeout (default value), but you might want to use something like HPA to add additional pods if your latency is increasing.

Comment: `timeout: 10` and `failureThreshold: 30` is very 'relaxed' I would say, you can have long downtime before you stop sending traffic/restarting, `periodSeconds: 8` * 30 = 4 minutes of possible downtime. I would make it more strict. but in this case possibly probes are not your problem (if you are seeing blips and not extended downtime) - unless you see your latency hovering around 10 seconds when it happens

Comment: I think you need to further profile your app and look at that possible memory leak you mentioned. if your pods are getting OOMKilled you might see pod restarts - not sure if this is the case

Comment: Yes very 'relaxed' i have downtime but still sometimes readiness & liveness failing i have seen logs in the cluster operation GKE. however, there is not log for killing container. In stack driver monitoring also pod not reaching to memory or cpu limit.

Comment: is it possible that your health check takes 10 seconds to respond in those cases? basically it means you had 30 consecutive healthcheck failures before readiness/liveness started failing. you need to understand why your healthchecks are failing, it could also be an upstream issue (depends on what your healthcheck actually checks).

Comment: health check failing randomly however we have simple health check endpoints return 204 response there is no logic behind i think under heavy load may be application not able to response health check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206894/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-eytan-avisror).